# In iOS, is it possible to set the badge count to the number of undismissed notifications a user has for an app?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, badge

So for instance, suppose 3 push notification are sent to an app. The push notifications would not include a badge count, because we want the badge count to be managed on the client.

When one notification comes in, the badge on the app is set to 1. When two more come in, the badge is increased to three.

*Then, when a user swipes away a notification*, the badge count is decremented back to 2. Thus, the badge itself doesn't show any number calculated by the server pushing the notification, but rather, the number of non-dismissed notifications on the client.

Is that possible in iOS?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there no way to run code when a user merely swipes away a notification, so I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but in this page, they are adding a custom dismiss action: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types

Comment: @koen is there a way, when the app does run, to determine how many notifications have not been dismissed even if the code doesn't run when it happens?

Comment: You mean when your app is terminated? Sorry, not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks, @koen. I guess "no, that's not possible" is the answer itself then.

Comment: @KenKinder Maybe it *is* possible, but I wouldn't know how.